# How to normalize this recursive nested JSON

Tags: normalization, normalize, normalizr

Having a bit of an issue trying to normalise the my payload that contains a nested schema of the same type as the parent using Normalizr

For example

```
{
  id: 123,
  sections:{
    section: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "test",
      sections: {
        section: {
          id: 125,
          name: "test125"
        }
      }
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "test2"
      sections: {
        section: [
          {
            id: 124,
            name: "test124"
          }
        ]
      }
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "test3"
    }]
  } 
}
```

In the above json structure, nested section may be an object or an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with nested comments. Here's how I solved it:

```
export const comment = new schema.Entity("comment", {}, {
    idAttribute: "key"
})
comment.define({
    user: user,
    reactions: {
        data: [reaction]
    },
    children: [comment]
})


export const post = new schema.Entity("post", {
    user: user,
    files: [image],
    comments: {
        data: [comment]
    },
    reactions: {
        data: [reaction]
    }
}, {
    idAttribute: "key"
})
```

Basically, I define `comment` as a new entity before I use it in its own entity definition. The other schemas I define as usual, in the constructor (see the `post` schema for an example). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filter which will normalize the data:

```
def enumerate:
  if type=="array" then .[] else . end ;
def sectionids:
    [ .sections.section | enumerate | .id // empty | tostring ]
  | if .==[] then {} else {sections:.} end ;
def sections:
    {sections:{section:[.]}}
  | .. | .section? | enumerate | objects | del(.sections) + sectionids ;

{
  "result": .id,
  "entities": {
    "sections": (reduce sections as $s ({};.["\($s.id)"]=$s))
  }
}
```

Sample Run (assumes proper json data in `data.json` and the above filter in `filter.jq`)

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
{
  "result": 123,
  "entities": {
    "sections": {
      "123": {
        "id": 123,
        "sections": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      },
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "sections": [
          "125"
        ]
      },
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "sections": [
          "124"
        ]
      },
      "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test3"
      },
      "125": {
        "id": 125,
        "name": "test125"
      },
      "124": {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "test124"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVHLboMwELznK1arHEAFRyXtxRHqh1AONGxaR8RQ26iKiH@9dCEhr6rqxZrdmZ3ZlbeffYeqRPmYLCO0tHaq1hZlN2GU2UkQoS52hBIdWYd/iCez5xs11@i9j45scsMl@E9u8nTn9YQ@P5stb8jlSB36kjZAut2RKRzJGYDagNs3lKZYGFPsEdwHaRBZDlRZAsHqElazYe60gCrtMAiQgZj2mwAcLu6MhSphsQDaNW7PpautM0q/Q87zhyFapCknjZGdPyZ2k6cU/nf4GH2RTEhmgs8bEsXwnLovd@vUb1smLKOSquC8fAgPV7dxXscZaMi2lUM5HBENDdJOOUX8F9CN91/9DgSGynZN5zWhsDC3EHR@JTJ8DeaWbULM07kNQ572M9/333Uzivs41m1VxUo3rePCFF9x3ToufgA)